# Geographical weighted regression

Tags: qgis

When i run a geographical weighted regression in QGIS, this command pops up 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details
and no regression analysis will happen. Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: I believe that you do not have a projection defined. The "crs" is the spatial reference string.

Comment: Iv defined a projection under properties for both shp. and csv. is there another way to define projection?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se! Please click 'edit' and give more information about your data and the steps you have followed.

Comment: You are going to have to add much more information to get a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a projected system set to run a GWR in QGIS (I think you do in ArcGIS as well). You cannot use a geographic coordinate system (GCS) you must set a projected system with linear units such as meters or feet. A simple answer may be to use your local UTM Zone. Can you post your shapefile ,prj to a public URL and Ill take a look.

Comment: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/points_in_polygon.html

Comment: I gathered the data from this website, im not sure how to convert shp. to url sorry